# Suggest database structure for storing users mutual score

Tags: database-design

I have three tables 
-Users
-Posts
-Activity (contain info of users likes or dislikes of posts).

My business requirement is to suggest people to follow each other based upon their likes and dislikes.

I have created a process, where mutual score is calculated based upon users likes and dislikes.

For example: user AA likes the post with id 100, than other users (say 50 users)  who also likes this post, I calculate score for user AA against all 50 users, by adding each common post(as 100 in above case, they can go into hundreds or more) like score, I suggest user AA the user to whom the user AA has highest mutual score.

My problem is that when I store the calculation for each user against other users (so that I need not to start process from beginning each time) in a flat table, the table becomes huge. Please suggest me best database table structure for storing this data of user’s mutual score

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a table space problem. If you calculate the scores between every pair of users, you'll get O(n^2) scores. You should probably use an heuristic to get more or less the ppl who seem to get a good score with every user, and calculate only the scores between those pairs (you could limit it to only calculate the best 10 users per each user). That way you'll use a lot of less space, and I'll work faster. All social networks and those kind of applications user heuristics and cheat when they make all their computations... You should do the same...